# How can I tell a fragment shader to not write a particular pixel?

Tags: graphics, graphics-programming, webgl

In a WebGL I'd like to send a screen space quad through that gets processed by a fragment shader, but have the fragment shader only write out a pixel under certain conditions (say... that it was within a circle, or that the pixel belonged to the positive side of a halfspace defined by a curve equation or something).

Is it possible within a fragment shader to say "don't write a pixel"?

I know this could be accomplished using various other methods like alpha blending, rendering this first and having it put the background color where it doesn't want to draw a pixel, or maybe doing some trick with the depth or stencil buffers.  I also know i could create a bunch of geometry to match what it is that I want to render.

Is there a way though to make the fragment shader choose not to write a pixel at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can `discard` in the fragment shader to avoid writing the pixel. [Here's a random example](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/discard.php) I dug up from Google.

Note that this may not actually stop the fragment shader from processing (as the GPU tends to process fragments in blocks; only discarding from all fragments in a block will abandon the processing). But the fragment won't be written to the output, which is basically what you want.

You may be interested in this related [question about the performance of `discard`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/do-i-lose-gain-performance-for-discarding-pixels-even-if-i-dont-use-depth-testi) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509051/is-discard-bad-for-program-performance-in-opengl) on SO.

I have no idea if this is supported in WebGL though. If it isn't, you'll need to fall back to one of your suggestions (like alpha blending; I think that would be the most straightforward).

Answer (score 4):

The `discard` statement comes in handy.

You didn't say too much about your decision path, so I'll offer an example using a simple texture lookup:

```
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_uv) * u_color;
    if (gl_FragColor.a <= 0.0) discard;
}
```

(That's from some sample code I wrote before I learned about alpha blending.)