# Better use background chromas or transparency?

Tags: 2d, godot, image, spritesheet, png

For `png`  2D sprites, its better use chromas or alpha channel?

- What is more performant during run-time processing?
- What uses less storage?
- Any difference between 2D & 3D?

*[using **Godot Engine**]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a shader in charge of displaying the sprites. This shader will have the logic to handle either the chroma key or the alpha channel.

If you use alpha channel, you will need to send more data to the GPU (the alpha channel). However, you wouldn't be sending the textures every frame, instead you send them on load and reuse them. Thus, the performance impact we are talking about is slightly more time on load and slightly more video memory used.

On the other hand, for the chroma key… Well, it depends. If you are going to make a single exact color transparent, then the shader is as performant as using alpha channel (with the drawback that you cannot specify levels of transparency). However, if you are going to set transparency depending on how close a color is to the chroma key, within some range. Then the shader code will  be more complicated, and thus less performance in runtime (the performance hit might or might not is perceptible).

---

I remind you that if you use chroma key, you lose the ability to use the color you picked for your chroma key.

I will also remind you that you will not be sending the PNG to the GPU. You will have to decode the PNG into a bitmap with a pixel format the GPU supports. And you would do that conversion in CPU.

And I will further remind you that the formats you use to develop do not have to match the formats you deploy. If you find it easier to develop with PNG with chroma key, you might as well have a tool that converts them to a format that supports transparency and can be loaded directly into GPU, and add that as a step to your build process.

---

There isn't a difference between 2D and 3D about how you encode transparency.

However… Unusually in 2D you would know in what order to render things, while in 3D you would rely on depth test (well, unless you are doing ray-tracing or something like that). Now, if the fragment shader writes depth or drops fragments, the GPU needs to runs the fragment shader before deciding what occludes what, and thus having things with transparency (by chroma key or alpha channel) slows everything down. The simple solution is to draw all the opaque geometry first, and then the potentially transparent geometry afterwards.

See also: [Do I lose/gain performance for discarding pixels even if I don't use depth testing?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/40301/10408)

---

You might also be interested in not having transparency. Instead create a mesh from the texture that only includes the opaque areas. This, of course, means more triangles. But it also means a simpler shader. Thus, you will have to decide if this trade-off is worth it for your game.

Comment: Theraot, thx for feedback. I'm using Godot Engine, for 2D based on sprites (Diablo-like). All the technical rendering pipeline stuff you described is auto.

Answer (score 1):

Transparency can be very costly on low end devices because the game has to do a lot of work to draw things in the right order (which obviously means more video memory). Of course it depends on the number and size of your objects so you'll have to test it to find out for sure.

Although a Chroma key solution would be more complicated so it's going to be a trade off.

There probably won't be any differences between 2D and 3D. I mean there's the perspective math you have to do but I don't think using transparency really changes that.

Comment: thx for answer, I use  Godot Engine, so it automates process